# Return row ID from StoredProcedure MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am attempting to return the value of the row for this statement:

```
INSERT INTO SystemName (SystemName)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT v_SystemName) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM SystemName WHERE SystemName = v_SystemName
) LIMIT 1;
SET id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If it actually does the insert I need it to return that row ID, otherwise it needs to return the new row ID. I tried to use LAST_INSERT_ID() but that didn't return what I needed because if it didn't do the insert it would give the wrong result. Does anyone have an idea that could make this work?

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Assuming your procedure only expects back the row ID and no further processing will be done you can try: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() doesn't do what I need it to for 2 reasons, 1.) It gives back the most recently inserted which this may not be if it doesn't do the insert, and 2.) It also returns the last inserted value for different tables in my database, so if a different one is inserted it will return that value rather than the value from this table.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I ended up doing was this, and I know it isn't the best solution because it isn't a transaction and could cause some issues but this is the only way I could get it to work.

```
INSERT INTO SystemName (SystemName)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT v_SystemName) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT * FROM SystemName WHERE SystemName = v_SystemName
) LIMIT 1;
SELECT id FROM SystemName WHERE SystemName = v_SystemName;
```

This way I don't need any out variables or anything, it just returns my id.